# Privacy concern with photos in people widget

Tags: gmail, privacy

I don't mind seeing other people's recent photos - but I *do* mind them seeing *mine*.  How can I make sure *my* recent photos are not showing up on other people's people widget?

Comment: Can I clarify which web application is this? I don't recall Gmail providing the functionality to see recent photos...

Comment: @Hydra: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-people-widget.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it displays content about you that's already in their email account because you sent it to them. In other words, if you sent them a photo, it's safe to assume you don't mind that photo showing up in their people widget.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Gmail support](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/1251806):

> Thumbnails of recent photos your contacts sent you

Says to me that the photos you'd see are the same you'd see if you visited the person's Google+ profile. There won't be any photos exposed to a person that you're not already letting them see.